# Bash-Completion Does not work for Apt

Tags: linux, debian, bashrc

I am running a **minimal Debian** installation that comes with practically nothing installed. I am trying to get bash auto-complete working. I have looked over all the questions on this subject in superuser and askubuntu sites and this is what I have found.

I understand that I need to install bash-completion. I installed that on my system. I found I have to have this in my `$HOME/.bashrc` file:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

That was already there. I read somewhere that it should be added to the `/etc/profile` file. I did that. I logged out and logged back in and it does not work. I added `&& echo "OK"` to the files and when I load the terminal it says OK so I know its running it.

Auto-complete for programs and paths works, but that always worked even before I installed bash-completion. The main thing that doesn't work that is bothering me is apt. If I say `sudo apt install ged` and then hit tab twice it will not give a list of packages that start with that string like it does in Ubuntu and other OSs.

**So basically, how can I get bash-completion to work with apt? Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 2):

What I had not noticed is that bash-completion has a folder in `/usr/share/bash-completion/` called completion with separate files for each program that it supports.

I copied the apt file from my Ubuntu box and put it in that folder on my minimal Debian box. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

## How I solved it

I had auto completion problems trying to autocomplete `wget` with `apt-get install wg[TAB][TAB]` and I managed to solve it by removing the `--no-generate` parameter from the flies below:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-cache
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
```

It is worth mentioning that these files are available only after you install `bash-completion`.

The `--no-generate` parameter I'm referring to can be seen in the line below, but I removed ALL  `--no-generate`, not only from this line: 
https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/apt-get#L28

## How did I come to this point?

I got to this point after running `set -v` previous to `apt-get install wg[TAB][TAB]`, which showed that the command executed was:

```
apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames wg
```

and the output was an error:

```
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

When I executed `apt-cache pkgnames wg` without the `--no-generate` I correctly got the list for autocompletion:

```
root@484f5c8f56ba:/# apt-cache pkgnames wg
wgalician-minimos
wget2
wgaelic
wget
wgerman-medical
wget2-dev
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds worthy of an upstream bug report, if you haven't already!

Comment: Are you able to reproduce on a fresh install? If no, don't report upstream!

Comment: Yes, to reproduce I just try to autocomplete in `ubuntu:18.04` or `ubuntu:16.04` docker container. It fails all the times.